# AASM: guard method being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, aasm

While testing (Rspec) my state transitions using aasm I am noticing that all of my :guard methods are being called twice.

For example:

```
event :process_shipping_label do
  transitions :from => :label_generated, :to => :label_sent, :guard => :sent_shipping_label?
  transitions :from => :label_generated, :to => :label_send_failed
end
```

...

```
def sent_shipping_label?
  some_other_method_call  
end
```

...

In my RSpec

```
it "should call some_other_method_call exactly once" do
  package.should_receive(:some_other_method_call) {}
  package.process_shipping_label
end
```

...
but getting

```
Failure/Error: package.should_receive(:some_other_method_call) {}
   (#<Artwork:0x007fafd5cbff48>).some_other_method_call?(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 2 times
```

What am I doing wrong here?